# Reverse Polish Notation - arrays, vectors, scalars in C

Tags: arrays, c, matrix, struct, rpn

I have a big problem. My teacher told me that I must write a program. I must use reverse polish notation for operations on vectors, matrices, scalars etc. For example, when you calculate, you write
4+5-6. In RPN, you will write this, in this way 45+6-. https://www.prodevelopertutorial.com/given-an-expression-in-reverse-polish-notation-evaluate-it-and-get-the-output-in-c/
I must write output into the file and show on the screen

But my program will be much more difficult.

1. I will not use in my calculations numbers, but vectors, scalars, matrices.
2. I must read values from a file
3. I must use shortcuts; V is Vector, S is Scalars, M is Matrix
4. In additions, I must use much more operations, not only simple operations
   but also

```
+ adding
- subtraction
* multiplication
/ division
T transpose of an array
. scalar product
x vector product
D determinant
R inverse matrix
```

This is my data file

```
S scalar1 3
S scalar2 5
V vector1 3
2 4 7
V vector2 3
3 6 1
M matrix_A 3 3
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
M matrix_B 3 3
9 8 7
6 5 4
3 2 1
```

You see that I must create structs that have shortcut M/V/S, name of the element, dimension (dimX and Y for Matrices), and values.
Later I will add in this data file operations like

```
matrix_A
matric_B
*
```

This is my file with io functions
operation_io.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define MAX_NAME 20
#define MAX_ARRAY_DIM 50

typedef struct Vector {
    char keyWordV;
    char name[MAX_NAME];
    int dim;
    double data[MAX_ARRAY_DIM];
} Vector;

typedef struct Scalar {
    char keyWordS;
    char name[MAX_NAME];
    double data;
} Scalar;

typedef struct Matrix {
    char keyWordM;
    char name[MAX_NAME];
    int dimX;
    int dimY;
    double data[MAX_ARRAY_DIM][MAX_ARRAY_DIM];
} Matrix;

typedef struct Element {
    char type;
    union {
        Scalar s;
        Vector v;
        Matrix m;
    } elem;
} Element;

void readScalar(FILE *file, Scalar* s) {
    fscanf(file, " %s ", &s->name[0]);
    fscanf(file, "%10lf", &s->data);
    }
    
void writeScalar(FILE *file, Scalar* s) {
    fprintf(file, "S");
    fprintf(file, " %s \n", s->name);
    fprintf(file, "%10.2lf \n", s->data);
    }

void showScalar(Scalar* s) {
    printf("S");
    printf(" %s \n", s->name);
    printf("%10.2lf \n", s->data);
    }
    
void readVector(FILE *file, Vector* v) {
    fscanf(file, " %s %d ", &v->name[0], &v->dim);
    for (int j = 0; j < v->dim; ++j) {
        fscanf(file, "%10lf", &v->data[j]);
    }
}

void writeVector(FILE *file, Vector* v) {
    fprintf(file, "V");
    fprintf(file, " %s %d \n", v->name, v->dim);
    for (int j = 0; j < v->dim; ++j) {
        fprintf(file, "%10.2lf ", v->data[j]);
    }
    fprintf(file, "\n");
}

void showVector(Vector* v) {
    printf("V");
    printf(" %s %d \n", v->name, v->dim);
    for (int j = 0; j < v->dim; ++j) {
        printf("%10.2lf ", v->data[j]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}

void readMatrix(FILE *file, Matrix* m) {
    fscanf(file, " %s %d %d", &m->name[0], &m->dimX, &m->dimY);
    for (int i = 0; i < m->dimX; ++i)
        for (int j = 0; j < m->dimY; ++j)
            fscanf(file, "%10lf", &m->data[i][j]);
}

void writeMatrix(FILE *file, Matrix* m) {
    fprintf(file, "M");
    fprintf(file, " %s %d %d \n", m->name, m->dimX, m->dimY);
    for (int i = 0; i < m->dimX; ++i) 
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < m->dimY; ++j)
        {
            fprintf(file, "%10.2lf", m->data[i][j]);
        }
        fprintf(file, "\n");
    }
}

void showMatrix(Matrix* m) {
    printf("M");
    printf(" %s %d %d \n", m->name, m->dimX, m->dimY);
    for (int i = 0; i < m->dimX; ++i)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < m->dimY; ++j)
        {
            printf("%10.2lf", m->data[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
void readElement(FILE *file, Element* e) {
    char type;
    fscanf(file, " %c ", &type);
    switch (type) {
    case 'S':
        e->type = 'S';
        readScalar(file, &e->elem.s);
        writeScalar(file, &e->elem.s);
        showScalar(&e->elem.s);
        break;
    case 'V':
        e->type = 'V';
        readVector(file, &e->elem.v);
        writeVector(file, &e->elem.v);
        showVector(&e->elem.v);
        break;
    case 'M':
        e->type = 'M';
        readMatrix(file, &e->elem.m);
        writeMatrix(file, &e->elem.m);
        showMatrix(&e->elem.m);
        break;
    default:
        fputs("Error: unknown token!\n", stderr);
        exit(1);
    }
}

void policz(FILE *file, Element* e1, Element* e2, Element* e3)
{
    char type1, type2, type3;
    fscanf(file, " %c ", &type1);
    fscanf(file, " %c ", &type2);
    fscanf(file, " %c ", &type3);
    
}
int isOperator(char ch){
   if(ch == '+'|| ch == '-'|| ch == '*'|| ch == '/' || ch == '^')
      return 1;//character is an operator
   return -1;//not an operator
}
int isOperand(char ch){
   if(ch == 'S' || ch == 'V' || ch == 'M')
      return 1;//character is an operand
   return -1;//not an operand
}
#define MAX_D 256
double stack[MAX_D];
int depth;



void die(const char *msg)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "%s", msg);
    abort();
}
void push(double v)
{
    if (depth >= MAX_D) die("stack overflow\n");
    stack[depth++] = v;
}
 
double pop()
{
    if (!depth) die("stack underflow\n");
    return stack[--depth];
}
float operation(int a, int b, char op){ //bede dopiero pisal funkcje
   //Perform operation
   if(op == '+')
      return 1;
   else if(op == '-')
      return 1;
   else if(op == '*')
      return 1;
   else if(op == '/')
      return 1;
   else
      return 1; //return negative infinity
}
```

operation_io.h

```
#ifndef WEKTORY
#define WEKTORY

typedef struct Scalar Scalar;
typedef struct Vector Vector;
typedef struct Matrix Matrix;
typedef struct Element Element;

void readScalar(FILE *file, Scalar* s);
void writeScalar(FILE *file, Scalar* s);
void showScalar(Scalar* s);
void readVector(FILE *file, Vector* v);
void writeVector(FILE *file, Vector* v);
void showVector(Vector* v);
void readMatrix(FILE *file, Matrix* m);
void writeMatrix(FILE *file, Matrix* m);
void showMatrix(Matrix* m);
void readElement(FILE *file, Element* e);
void die(const char *msg);
void push(double v);
double pop();
float operation(int a, int b, char op);

#endif
```

This is my main program. main.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include "operation_io.h"
#define MAX_NAME 20
#define MAX_ARRAY_DIM 50


typedef struct Vector {
    char keyWordV;
    char name[MAX_NAME];
    int dim;
    double data[MAX_ARRAY_DIM];
} Vector;

typedef struct Scalar {
    char keyWordS;
    char name[MAX_NAME];
    double data;
} Scalar;

typedef struct Matrix {
    char keyWordM;
    char name[MAX_NAME];
    int dimX;
    int dimY;
    double data[MAX_ARRAY_DIM][MAX_ARRAY_DIM];
} Matrix;

typedef struct Element {
    char type;
    union {
        Scalar s;
        Vector v;
        Matrix m;
    } elem;
} Element;

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{    
    FILE *wz, *wc;  

    if (argc != 3) {                                
    printf("Wrong arguments number\n");
    printf("I should run this way:\n");
    printf("%s source\n",argv[0]);
    exit(1);
    }
    
    if( (wz= fopen(argv[1],"r")) == NULL) {
        printf("Open error %s\n", argv[1]);
        exit(1);
    }
    if( (wc= fopen(argv[2], "w")) == NULL) {
    printf("Open error %s\n", argv[2]);
    exit(2);
    }


    Element elements[10];
    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        readElement(wz, &elements[i]);
    }
    fclose(wz);
    fclose(wz);
    
    return 0;

}
```

MY file with the arithmetic operation. operation_m.c is empty because I'm not started with writing these functions because I have a problem.
I want to use algorithm like that https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Parsing/RPN_calculator_algorithm#C
But my case is more complicated because I am not using numbers and I have more operations (not only +,-,*,=)

I have 3 problems right now

1. My writing functions aren't working, but my functions with showing on the screen works perfect.
2. I dont know, how my program will know that I use matrix, vector or scalar?
   For example I have

```
matrix_A
matrix_B
*
```

how my program will know that name matrix_A and matrix_B means the multiplication of 2 matrices and use function multMatrices() (I haven't written this functions yet, but I will). I have an Idea. I want to connect name with a shortcut. So my program will find that I want to multiplicate matrices not for example scalar and matrix. I have my objects here - array of elements

```
    Element elements[10];
    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        readElement(wz, &elements[i]);
    }
```

so I must know how to use a proper element from this array, so how to do that?

3. In this algorithm I dont have unary operations https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Parsing/RPN_calculator_algorithm#C but in my program I will have like transpose of matrix etc. So I must add some if in switch case probably???

Comment: warning `456+-` is `4-(5+6)` not `4+5-6`

Comment: `how my program will know that I use matrix, vector or scalar? For example I have matrix_A
matrix_B
*` you need a dictionary to find an element from its name

Comment: You know what objects `*` is supposed to be applied to by examining the stack.  If the top two items on the stack are matrices, then `*` is a matrix operation.  If the top two objects on the stack are incompatible, you throw an error.

Comment: `printf(...); exit(1);` is a bug.  It should be either `fprintf(stderr, ...); exit(1);` or `printf(...); exit(0);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 2. I dont know, how my program will know that I use matrix, vector or scalar? For example I have
>
>    matrix_A
>    matrix_B
>    *
>    how my program will know that name matrix_A and matrix_B means the multiplication of 2 matrices and use function multMatrices()

you need a dictionary associating name (`char*`) to *Element*, because you will have very probably few definitions there is no performance problem and it is useless to use complex structures and to implement a *map* using hashing, or balanced tree etc.

Then having for instance a binary operation the valid case is to have at least 2 *Element* pushed in the stack and you just have to check their *type* to decide what function to call. Note you can also use 0, 1, 2 for the type allowing to use an array of pointer to function.

Are the type of the operand must be the same ? It may be allowed to multiply/add/divide/substract a vector/matrix by a scalar for instance, applying the operation on each cell ?

In *Vector* the attribute *keyWordV*, in *Scalar* the attribute *keyWordS* is useless, in *Matrix* the attribute *keyWordM* is useless.

It is also useless to have the attribute *name* in *Vector/Scalar/Matrix*, you just need to have it in *Element* at the same level of *type* (out of the `union`)

To use fixed size array in *Vector/Scalar/Matrix* is practical but that use more memory than necessary and what you will do if a number of element is greater than *MAX_ARRAY_DIM* or if a name is greater than *MAX_NAME* ?
Same for `Element elements[10];`.

> 1. My writing functions aren't working, but my functions with showing on the screen works perfect

how is it possible, the *writeX* and *showX* functions are exactly the same and in fact `showX(x)` can be defined as `writeX(stdout, x)`

> 3. In this algorithm I dont have unary operations ...

Frankly the reverse polish notation is so simple to implement you can do that by yourself from scratch, and doing that you will learn more ;-)

Whatever *n* an *n*nary operator pops its *n* operand(s) from the stack (of course check there are at least *n* element else indicate the error), computes the result, then pushes the result, trivial